# How do I increase a value in the middle of a number range in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to create a range of numbers as follows;

```
01-01-00
01-02-00
01-03-00
01-04-00
```

and so on....

I wish to run it horizontally across a spread sheet. I only get an increase in the 3rd value when pulled across.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

This formula will parse the parts:

```
=LEFT(A1,3) & TEXT(MID(A1,4,2)+1,"00") & RIGHT(A1,3)
```

Put `01-01-00` in A1 then the formula in B1 and drag/copy to the right.

[image]